# problem in get the yahoo contacts webservice

Tags: oauth, contacts, yahoo, yahoo-api

I try get the yahoo contacts by BBauth but when i finish i get this error:

The token is for SSO only

i try serch about this problem but there is no luck, hope you can help why get this problem

Answer (score 1):

The BBAuth access for Yahoo Contacts (aka Address Book) was deprecated in 2010 and I believe it no longer works.

Instead, you can access Contacts via YQL and OAuth authentication. Latest docs are here: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/